# Qual é a diferença TEXT e LONGTEXT?

Tags: mysql

Estou elaborando um sistema onde vou importar os dados de um Excel. Como esses dados serão temporários, pretendo salvar as informações dessa coluna importada em formato `JSON` no banco.

Sendo assim, eu fiquei na dúvida entre usar `TEXT` ou `LONGTEXT`.

É claro que esse caso é apenas um exemplo, mas há outros casos onde a dúvida vem em mente, por exemplo, na hora de salvar uma publicação de um sistema de blogs no banco. Eu teria que usar `TEXT` ou `LONGTEXT`?

Eu imagino que tenha diferença apenas por causa dos nomes, e não por conhecer detalhes técnicos da diferença entre um e outro.

Então a minha pergunta é:

- Qual é a diferença entre `LONGTEXT`  e `TEXT`?
- Usar `LONGTEXT` faria meu banco utilizar mais recursos do que usar `TEXT`?
- Existe diferença de velocidade de leitura ou performance ao escolher um ou outro?
- Em que casos eu teria que usar `LONGTEXT` ao invés de `TEXT`?

<sub>**NOTA**: Na verdade, eu nem quero que na resposta alguém aponte o que eu deveria fazer com esses meus dados que estou importando, mas gostaria apenas de saber qual é a diferença entre os dois tipos (LONGTEXT e TEXT). Até mesmo porque eu sei que a versão nova do MYSQL tem o formato *JSON*, mas isso é outra história, já que não uso a versão nova do MYSQL*.</sub>

Comment: Comprima a string utilizando [messagepack](https://msgpack.org/)

Comment: @MarcosPaulo já faz um tempo que o messagepack meio que foi deixado de lado -> https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/ (não que tenha problema nenhum em usar, só comentei pra dar ciência)

Answer (score 13):

Na [Documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-type-overview.html) tu vai encontrar muito sobre cada tipo, resumindo em Tamanhos:

```
      Tipo | Tamanho Máximo
-----------+--------------------------------------
  TINYTEXT |           255 (2^ 8−1) bytes         
      TEXT |        65,535 (2^16−1) bytes = 64 KiB
MEDIUMTEXT |    16,777,215 (2^24−1) bytes = 16 MiB
  LONGTEXT | 4,294,967,295 (2^32−1) bytes =  4 GiB
```

- Qual é a diferença entre LONGTEXT e TEXT? 
  Alocação de Memória Máxima (tamanho) como a Tabela acima;
- Usar LONGTEXT faria meu banco utilizar mais recursos do que usar TEXT?
  Exatamente, para cada linha no seu Banco seria necessário reservar, limpar, validar mais memória.
- Existe diferença de velocidade de leitura ou performance ao escolher um ou outro?
  As diferenças de Performance são poucas em pequenas Bases (você praticamente não se preocupa com performance em bases com dezenas ou poucas centenas de resultados), mas podem ser muito palpáveis para as grandes (1TB+), então a resposta é: sim.
- Em que casos eu teria que usar LONGTEXT ao invés de TEXT?
  Quando for armazenar mais de 16Mi Chars. Armazenar um livro todo, ou toda a informação de uma imagem RAW, por exemplo.

Comment: Creio que sua resposta não responda a pergunta exatamente, há outros questionamentos que essa figura não responde.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Concordo e fiz uma boa edição na resposta.

Comment: A diferença de tamanho entre eles me faz pensar que seria melhor se houvesse outras opções. Se alguns de meus textos tiverem um tamanho de, digamos, 66.000 bytes, eu sou obrigado a optar por MEDIUMTEXT o que para o meu caso é muito grande. Ou ter dois campos TEXT e tratar essa separação e junção no codigo?

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo a única diferença é quantos bytes pra guardar o comprimento, só isso. A resposta está totalmente equivocada no segundo ponto. Guardar um texto de 5000 bytes numa coluna TEXT gasta dois bytes a menos só do que se guardar numa LONGTEXT.